# Select MySQL Database in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I know I can call a database in the mysql.connector.connect method. However, I'm trying to programmatically create the database if it doesn't already exist, then connect too to upload table data.

Currently my line `cursor.execute("SELECT DATABASE myDatabase")` is generating an error in my "SQL syntax".

How can I check if a database exists and then connect to it?

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user=os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_USER'),
    password=os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_USER_PASS')
)

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDatabase")
cursor.execute("SELECT DATABASE myDatabase")

# create table on database
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trades` (`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `objectid` VARCHAR(100), `type` VARCHAR(5), `ownerid` VARCHAR(100), `color` VARCHAR(15), `shape` VARCHAR(15), `size` VARCHAR(15), PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );"
print(sql)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: MySQL syntax is `use myDatabase;`.  Or, skip this and reference the database in the statement itself as: `create table myDatabase.table1 ... ;` or `select * from myDatabase.column1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-database.html), the syntax is:

```
CREATE DATABASE `db_name`;
```

Then to select/change the database, use:

```
USE `db_name`;
```

To list all available databases, use:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

---

Alternatively, you can skip the `USE` command and reference the database in the statement itself as:

```
CREATE TABLE `db_name`.`table1` ... ;
```

Or, in the case of a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_name`.`table1`;
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, the `database` property can be used of the `MySQLConnection` object, as per the [MySQL Connector documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-database.html) (which executes the `USE` command for you):

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user=os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_USER'),
    password=os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_USER_PASS')
)

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDatabase")
db.database = 'myDatabase'
```

(I was dealing with the same issue and stumbled upon this post, after which I found the described solution. So thought I'd share this alternative solution for anyone interested.)